# why mysql not excute this update join statment

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to compare two tables by inner join and update the columns in table d_family by edit_27_5 table columns ..but something wrong..i tried more solution but it ditint work good

i see this message ( **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET d_family.city = edit_27_5.city, SET d_family.fa_name = edit_27_5.fa_n' at line 3**)

```
  UPDATE d_family  INNER JOIN edit_27_5
      ON 
  d_family.fa_id  =  edit_27_5.fa_id
  SET d_family.area  =  edit_27_5.area,
  SET d_family.city  =  edit_27_5.city,
  SET d_family.fa_name  =  edit_27_5.fa_name,
  SET d_family.fa_nationality  =  edit_27_5.nath,
  SET d_family.fa_phone_number  =  edit_27_5.phone,
  SET d_family.fa_mobile_number  =  edit_27_5.mobile,
  SET d_family.fa_account_anstaqram  =  edit_27_5.anst,
  SET d_family.fa_account_mail  =  edit_27_5.email,
  SET d_family.fa_account_twitter  =  edit_27_5.twit,
  SET d_family.fa_account_facebook  =  edit_27_5.face,
  SET d_family.fa_product_desc  =  edit_27_5.pt_desc,
  SET d_family.product_type  =  edit_27_5.pt_type,
  SET d_family.fa_markting_type  =  edit_27_5.markting
      WHERE d_family.fa_id  < 7221
```

Comment: Don't repeat `set` on the separate lines.  One `set`, multiple equalities.  Also, you are missing one of the table aliases in the `on` clause.

Comment: 3rd line .fa_id is edit_27_5.fa_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE d_family  INNER JOIN edit_27_5
  ON 
  d_family.fa_id  =  edit_27_5.fa_id
```

You were missing the joining part

```
d_family.fa_id  =  .fa_id
```

Also its wrong to have set multiple time

So the syntax is

```
update table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
set 
t1.col1 = t2.col1,
t1.col2 = t2.col,
......
```

In your case it should be something as

```
UPDATE d_family  
INNER JOIN edit_27_5 ON d_family.fa_id  =  edit_27_5.fa_id
SET 
d_family.area  =  edit_27_5.area,
d_family.city  =  edit_27_5.city,
d_family.fa_name  =  edit_27_5.fa_name,
d_family.fa_nationality  =  edit_27_5.nath,
d_family.fa_phone_number  =  edit_27_5.phone,
d_family.fa_mobile_number  =  edit_27_5.mobile,
d_family.fa_account_anstaqram  =  edit_27_5.anst,
d_family.fa_account_mail  =  edit_27_5.email,
d_family.fa_account_twitter  =  edit_27_5.twit,
d_family.fa_account_facebook  =  edit_27_5.face,
d_family.fa_product_desc  =  edit_27_5.pt_desc,
d_family.product_type  =  edit_27_5.pt_type,
d_family.fa_markting_type  =  edit_27_5.markting
WHERE d_family.fa_id  < 7221
```